# Laravel 5.3 отображения части контента для незарегистрированных пользователей

Tags: php, laravel

Вопрос по поводу отображения части контента для незарегистрированных пользователей.

Дело в том что в контроллере, который выдает вьюшку, я использую проверку на авторизацию через конструктор:

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

После перехода на страничку незарегистрированным пользователем осуществляется переход на `/login` то есть страницу для входа в систему.
 Так вот как можно передать для всех действий данного контроллера, к примеру короткое описание раздела закрытого контента (чтобы пользователь мотивировался зарегистрироваться).

Просто будет около 3 частей приложения подобной этой, а идей совсем нет. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: как вариант показывать разные шаблоны для зареганых/незареганых, или пускать в контроллере, но показывать блоки в шаблоне по проверке на авторизацию

Comment: Я такой вариант рассматривал, но не хотел лезть с логикой в шаблон)

Comment: тогда разные шаблоны

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос решился добавлением куки для логики, через стандартную функцию setcookie